# Single Entrance Restriction

Tags: remix, ethereumjs, solidity

Please suggest that how two restric subscriber for single entry means no one can join twice.

```
function selectionW1(address subscribersW1, uint subscriberWheelW1) public  {

    require (subscriberWheelW1 == 1 && subscriberListW1.length < 2);
    subscriberListW1.push(subscribersW1);
    subscriberstructsW1[subscribersW1].W1 = subscriberWheelW1;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mapping of bools to check if the user has already used the function:

```
mapping(address => bool) public registered.

function selectionW1(address subscribersW1, uint subscriberWheelW1) public  {

    require (subscriberWheelW1 == 1 && subscriberListW1.length < 2);
    require(!registered[msg.sender])
    registered[msg.sender] = true;
    subscriberListW1.push(subscribersW1);
    subscriberstructsW1[subscribersW1].W1 = subscriberWheelW1;

}
```

That will do. Hope this helps you.